# TypeConverter alternative in .Net Standard 1.6

Tags: c#, exception, type-conversion, .net-standard

I am using reflection in my project.

In some cases I need to cast/convert string I have retrieved from web page source to other types like int , etc.

I created method with this signature :

```
internal static T GetData<T>(parameter,parameter)
```

So if Framework-user want to get int , easily use `GetData<int>`

I want to add exception handling to my method *instead of try/catch*

for checking if String can cast to T.

**The problem is that TypeConverter class is not available in .NetStandard.**

```
    TypeConverter typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(string));

    if (typeConverter.CanConvertTo(typeof(T)) == false)
    {
        throw new InvalidCastException("Can not convert");
    }
```

[image: Error]

I want to check the conversion, **using native features of .Net , NOT using third party libraries or try/catch**.
How can I do this ?

Comment: TypeConverter can be a bit of a crutch.  It is here, this code retrieves StringConverter.  It doesn't do anything useful, nobody really needs help converting from a string to a string.  Makes it hard to recommend a replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this extension method.

**To simulate TypeConverter**.

Maybe it is insane or .... ? 
but it works for me.

I will be happy to hear your opinion about this solution and better ideas or additions to this method.

```
        internal static bool CanConvertTo(this Type originType, Type destinationType)
        {
            if (originType == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("parameter originType is null");
            }

            if (destinationType == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("parameter destinationType is null");
            }


#if !(NETSTANDARD1_3 || NETSTANDARD1_6)
            TypeConverter typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(originType);

            if (typeConverter.CanConvertTo(destinationType) == false)
            {
                return false;
            }
#endif


#if NETSTANDARD1_3 || NETSTANDARD1_6
            try
            {
                object tester;
                tester = Convert.ChangeType(originType,destinationType);
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
#endif

            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

One simple option is to update to .NET Standard 2.0:

[image]

Comment: thanks for answering but the project I am contributing in it is multi-target project and it's not mine, maybe the project owner does not like to upgrade it , I really don't know !

Comment: @Parsa if you're talking about HTML Agility Pack, there is already a 2.0 folder.  Before 2.0, the closest you have is probably `Convert.ChangeType`